# How to change the menu humberger icon color and logo depending on the background color

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, navbar, elementor

I have a WordPress website. I used Elementor to build the website and now, I have a black navbar that is visible on all pages.

I want to change the color of the hamburger icon and the logo depending on the background color.

I think I can achieve such an effect if I added a specific class to each section that has a dark background to change the navbar. I think I can achieve that with some Javascript.

Here is the kinda effect I'm talking about:
http://preview.themeforest.net/item/ernest-creative-portfolio-theme/full_screen_preview/36672824?_ga=2.264165004.1294616065.1649947995-1883984429.1649947995&_gac=1.13822533.1649978693.CjwKCAjw0a-SBhBkEiwApljU0p6Qxl8eXyEN-ErwX2M9uPx9RrXM5TFFo-P8Qi8ENHRnOd2VgD-sQxoCFs8QAvD_BwE

Does anyone know how I can achieve such an effect?

Comment: Please put in relevant code so we can see your HTML structure and what is there already - in particular what is 'the background color' the background color of?

Comment: I don't have a code. I used Elementor to build the website, and Elementor is a visual drag-and-drop builder so it uses code in the back-end. I can write custom code if I want so that is not a problem. But currently, I don't have any code that approaches the effect I want.

Comment: Do you need to look at the code that is actually being run? e.g. through browser dev tools to see what has been created? Otherwise how can you know what is setting that color?

Comment: I don't really understand but, I want to achieve something similar to the link I have put in the comments. I know Elementor can't do something like that but I can achieve with code but I'm not sure how